# OAuth 2.0 with Authorization Code Grant Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am working with TCN API:https://auth.tcn.com/authorize

It uses OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant. The Authorization Code grant type is used by confidential and public clients to exchange an authorization code for an access token.

Anyone gives me a sample for this flow? My pleasure if anyone used this API before.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Do you want to generate an access token using a refresh token?

Comment: yes, need code for (asp.net + C#)